# This page uses a selectbox jquery plugin to be styleable, but I'm having difficulty styling it

Tags: jquery, css

See http://colin.jciuk.creativestateservers.co.uk/local-chambers/

The dropdown on the left, "SELECT CHAMBER", in anything other than Firefox, has more padding on the top than on the bottom, and anything that I adjust seems to make no difference.

Can anyone tell what needs to be changed to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the .selectbox stylesheet(in the http://colin.jciuk.creativestateservers.co.uk/sites/jciuk.org.uk/resources/css/all.css)

background-position: 0px 4px;

Comment: Thanks, definite progress though.  It also means the dropdown is not aligned to the main image.  I tried increasing the negative margin on div.selectbox-wrapper ul but it seems to do nothing.

Comment: Managed to shift over the dropdown with the margin in div.selectbox, though I'm realising what i actually need to do is shift the background back over. Have used background-position: 4px 4px but this still is not right in Firefox.